Kafka dissconnecting after few days
We are using Kafka for data exchange between microservices in NestJS and Java. We have an API Gateway in NestJS and a user service in Java. We are facing an issue with Kafka disconnecting after a few days. What could be causing this issue?
Here is the error we got:
ERROR [ServerKafka] ERROR [Runner] The coordinator is not aware of this member, re-joining the group {"timestamp":"2024-07-25T10:45:02.565Z","logger":"kafkajs","groupId":"flights-consumer-server","memberId":"nestjs-consumer-server-3fc36120-7844-4785-9211-89fe2647291e","error":"The coordinator is not aware of this member"}

Here is my docker-compose .yaml file for the Kafka service:

services:
  kafka-broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka-broker-1
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://:19092,EXTERNAL://:9092,CONTROLLER://kafka-broker-1:9093"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@kafka-broker-1:9093
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      CLUSTER_ID: 'lFakshjkdN5OsydWA3ynLHQ=='
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka-broker-1:19092,EXTERNAL://10.31.1.31:9092"
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 10485760  # 10 MB
      KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 10485760   # 10 MB
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: 1073741824 # 1 GB
      KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY: delete
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/kafka/data
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - my-network

  kafdrop-1:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka-broker-1:19092"  # Adjust ports if necessary
    depends_on:
      - kafka-broker-1
    networks:
      - my-network


networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge


